# Ten fold classification and using lib svm to calculate accuracy in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, libsvm

I have a term-document matrix and the corresponding label matrix I have to divide the data set into 10 parts and use any random 7 parts for training the libsvm classifier and test on the remaining 3 parts.
I have to do this for all possible cases i.e. 10C7.
Here is the code for training and testing using SVM, I am unable to understand how to classify and iterate for all cases.

```
m = svm_train(labels[0:2000], rows_1[0:2000], '-c '+str(k)+' -g '+str(g))

p_label, p_acc, p_val = svm_predict(labels[2000:0], rows_1[2000:0], m)
acc.append(p_acc)
```

Where 'labels' is the label array and 'rows_1' are rows of term document matrix.
I am new to this please help!

Comment: Why 7 for training and 3 for testing?

Comment: as you tagged this scikit-learn, the standard version of cross-validation would be ```cross_val_score(SVM(), rows_1, labels, cv=10)``` which would do 10-fold stratified cross-validation.
You are not using stratification, which will give you more noisy estimates in all likelihood as different folds will have different class balances.

Answer (score 3):

You have to shuffle your data and create indices for the training and test folds. For example, if you have 2000 training examples and you want to use 10 folds, then you will have:

```
fold1
  test[0:200]
  train[200:2000]
fold2
  test[200:400]
  train[0:200, 400:2000]
etc
```

Here is a sample code in Python:

```
import numpy as np
indices = np.random.permutation(2000)  # create a list of 2000 unique numbers in random order
n_folds = 10
fold_step = int(2000 / n_folds)
acc = []
for fold in range(0, 2000, fold_step):
    test_labels = [labels[i] for i in indices[fold:fold+fold_step]]
    train_labels = [l for l in labels if l not in test_labels]
    test_rows = [rows_1[i] for i in indices[fold:fold+fold_step]]
    train_rows = [r for r in rows_1 if r not in test_rows]

    m = svm_train(train_labels, train_rows, '-c '+str(k)+' -g '+str(g))
    p_label, p_acc, p_val = svm_predict(test_labels, test_rows, m)
    acc.append(p_acc)

print("Accuracy: {}%".format(np.mean(acc)))
```